# How to move many different sub folders one level down?

Tags: linux, shell-script, directory, move

I have a LARGE amount of files in the following structure
all files in /base/, then 4 folders with 2 "random" letters, and then a series of files related to each other.

Example:

```
/base/ab/12/13/37/file1.txt
/base/ab/12/13/37/file2.txt
/base/ab/12/13/37/file3.txt
/base/cd/b8/e2/a1/other1.txt
.... 
/base/cd/b8/e2/a1/other52.txt
/base/af/f3/45/9e/third1.txt
/base/af/f3/45/9e/third2.txt
```

etc

I want to keep most of the structure, but add one ADDITIONAL (extra_folder) folder at the end, in which my files belong.
Such that the above is changed to:

```
/base/ab/12/13/37/extra_folder/file1.txt
/base/ab/12/13/37/extra_folder/file2.txt
/base/ab/12/13/37/extra_folder/file3.txt
/base/cd/b8/e2/a1/extra_folder/other1.txt
```

I expect that I will need a shell script and the move command.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a script. You could try to do something, probably based on `for`, `sed` and/or `find`,and get back to us should you have any problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we start with:

```
$ tree base/
base/
|-- ab
|   `-- 12
|       `-- 13
|           `-- 37
|               |-- file1.txt
|               |-- file2.txt
|               `-- file3.txt
|-- af
|   `-- f3
|       `-- 45
|           `-- 9e
|               |-- third1.txt
|               `-- third2.txt
`-- cd
    `-- b8
        `-- e2
            `-- a1
                |-- other1.txt
                `-- other52.txt

12 directories, 7 files
```

First we add the new directories:

```
$ find base -type d -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4 -exec mkdir {}/extra_folder ';'
```

We use both `-mindepth 4` and `-maxdepth 4` to create new directories on level four only. Without the `-mindepth 4` we would get new directories on higher levels, and without `-maxdepth 4` the new directories would themselves be filled with new directories until the pathnames became so long that `find` no longer was able to create more.

The `extra_folder` directory is created with `mkdir` called from `-exec`.
Now we have

```
$ tree base/
base/
|-- ab
|   `-- 12
|       `-- 13
|           `-- 37
|               |-- extra_folder
|               |-- file1.txt
|               |-- file2.txt
|               `-- file3.txt
|-- af
|   `-- f3
|       `-- 45
|           `-- 9e
|               |-- extra_folder
|               |-- third1.txt
|               `-- third2.txt
`-- cd
    `-- b8
        `-- e2
            `-- a1
                |-- extra_folder
                |-- other1.txt
                `-- other52.txt

15 directories, 7 files
```

Then we'll move the files down:

```
$ find base -maxdepth 5 -type f -execdir mv {} extra_folder ';'
```

This looks for any regular file in or under the `base` directory (I'm assuming there are files only on the lowest level) that are on level five. It then uses `-execdir` to run the `mv` command inside the directory where the found file is located (`{}` will be the basename of the found file).

We end up with

```
$ tree base/
base/
|-- ab
|   `-- 12
|       `-- 13
|           `-- 37
|               `-- extra_folder
|                   |-- file1.txt
|                   |-- file2.txt
|                   `-- file3.txt
|-- af
|   `-- f3
|       `-- 45
|           `-- 9e
|               `-- extra_folder
|                   |-- third1.txt
|                   `-- third2.txt
`-- cd
    `-- b8
        `-- e2
            `-- a1
                `-- extra_folder
                    |-- other1.txt
                    `-- other52.txt

15 directories, 7 files
```

---

In one go:

```
$ find base -type f \
    -execdir sh -c '[ ! -d "$1" ] && mkdir "$1"; mv "$2" "$1"' sh 'extra_folder' {} ';'
```

This finds all regular files and moves them into a directory called `extra_folder` regardless of where they are to start with.  Running this command multiple time will move them further and further down.

The mini-script that is called by `-execdir`:

```
[ ! -d "$1" ] && mkdir "$1"
mv "$2" "$1"
```

This will be called with the folder name as `$1` and with the filename as `$2` and will create the folder if it doesn't exist and then move the file into it.

Comment: I tested the first commands. Has to be done in two steps, but they appear to work :) Thank you.